# Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I have installed all prerequisites for setting up the hyperledger Explorer but when I start it, I got the following error in log file:

[image]
And my config.json file is this:

[image]
Postgres' command also done:

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHUn6.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTpSY.png

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz8fG.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IocQU.png

Comment: I have attached image of the log file and config file

Comment: What version of explorer, are you trying to install?

Comment: I am following from these instructions: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

Answer (score 0):

You're database setup is not done correctly, run these commands one by one.

## Database setup

**Connect to PostgreSQL database**

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

**Run create database script**

```
\i app/db/explorerpg.sql
\i app/db/updatepg.sql
```

**Run db status commands.**

```
\l view created fabricexplorer database
\d view created tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it postgres database error ...
In your error its clearly said that the chaincode_id doesnt exit ... so this is the problem .
if you want check what column are existed in the transaction table just follow below step

```
 cd blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/postgreSQL/db

 sudo -u postgres psql

 \d transactions
```

check the corresponding column chaincode_id exist or not (it wont exist now ,Thats why you got this error)....

**Solution for this type error**

If you got any error like this first just go to the blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/postgreSQL/db directory

There you can see two file explorerpg.sql and updatepg.sql open this two file and check the corresponding column if existed on any of this file or not. If not you better to download explorer another version which contain the corresponding columns either of this two file mentioned above.

if existed just run below command on ubuntu

```
     cd blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/postgreSQL/db                 

     sudo -u postgres psql

     \i explorerpg.sql

     \i updatepg.sql
```

*Once done this command just check the column "chaincode_id " is created or not by*

```
     \d transactions
```

it will list all column just check it on.

if the chaincode_id is exist run the explorer again ....